# How to fetch limited data from mysql java

Tags: java, mysql, resultset, large-data

Can I limit the number of rows in result set?
My table contains some 800000 rows, if I fetch them in result set, this will definitely lead to OOM exception. each row has 40 columns. 
I do not want to want work on them at the same time, but each row is to be filtered out for some data.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please show  your sql query ?

Comment: You can add something like top 1000 (or) limit 0, 1000. Limit works for sure in mysql workbench, don't know in java code.

Comment: Can you provide the java code? It's unlikely that the java db driver will load all rows until memory and will only load rows as you need them.

Comment: @ Suresh atta:

  PreparedStatement ps =  con.prepareStatement("select * from table");
  ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
 

  if(rs.next()){

   System.out.println(rs.first());
  }
I get outofmemory error. I knew it. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like following should be a SQL solution but albeit rather ineffective, since each time you will have to fetch the increasing amount of rows.

Assuming that you have your ORDER BY is based on **unique** `int` and 
that you will be fetching 1000 rows at a time.

```
SET currenttop = 0;
SET cuurentid = 0;
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
WHERE t1.ID > @currentID AND (@currentid := t1.ID) IS NOT NULL; 
LIMIT (@currenttop:=@currenttop+1000);
```

Of course you can choose to handle variable from your Java code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [JDBC fetch size](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize%28int%29) to limit the result in the result set. It is better than the SQL **LIMIT** as it will work for other database as well without changing the query. Jdbc diriver will not read the whole result from the database. Each time it will retrieve the records specified by the fetch size and there will be no memory issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `limit` keyword with sql query, see following

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15
```

You can read more about using `limit` [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Cheers !!

Comment: ResulSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement ps =  con.prepareStatement("select * from table");

ps.setFetchSize(100);
rs = ps.executeQuery("select * from table");



if(rs.next()){ 
             System.out.println(rs.first());
             }

This doesn't work as expected.

Comment: ps.setMaxRows(20); 
This works. 
It fetches only 20 rows at a time

Answer (score -1):

You have a couple options. First, add a limit to the SQL query. Second, you could use [JDBCTemplate.query()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query%28org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreator,%20org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowCallbackHandler%29) with a [RowCallbackHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowCallbackHandler.html) to process one row at a time. The template will handle memory issues with a large result set.

Comment: Could you specify how it manages the memory issue. I think your answer is misleading

Comment: It loads a limited number of results at a time. I don't know the exact number of the alg but it grabs the results in batches to be passed to the handler one at a time.

Comment: Spring Jdbc template is a wrapper on standard JDBC API. It uses the same jdbc method to set the fetch size, Please see, http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#setFetchSize%28int%29